# Classification rate Weka Java API

Tags: java, weka, j48

I would like to get the classification rate for a tree constructed using J48.

```
DataSource source = new DataSource(Path);
Instances data = source.getDataSet();
J48 tree = tree.buildClassifier(data);
```

I know it has something to do with

```
public double getMeasure(java.lang.String additionalMeasureName)
```

But i can't find the correct String (additionalMeasureName) to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer to my question using Evaluation class. The code should be:

```
//Learning
DataSource source = new DataSource(Path);
Instances data = source.getDataSet();
J48 tree = new J48();
tree.buildClassifier(data);

//Evaluation
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
eval.evaluateModel(tree, data);
System.out.println((eval.correct()/data.numInstances())*100);
```

This tests the decision tree using the learning data an displays the percentage of correctly classified instances.